# positioning a jquery dialog that is inside an iframe realtive to the parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

hallo all

i have a site which has a very big scroll on it, and there is an iframe in the middle 
set to have no scroll and its height is 3000

anyway the document being opened in the iframe has a jquery dialog in it.

when im looking at the top of the parent 
and click a button inside the iframe that opens the dialog
the dialog opens at the middle of the iframe and i cant see it...

thats because its doing its calcualtions based on the document not the top document

how can i change that?

so if my scroll was all the way down in the parent the dialog inside the iframe will open at the bottom of the iframe where i can see it.. in other words realtive to positon of parent document.

this is how i open my dialog:

```
generalDialog.dialog({
   bgiframe:false, height:p_height, width:480, modal:true, autoOpen:false, hide:'fadeout', show:'slide', closeOnEscape:true}); generalDialog.dialog("open");
```

thanks in advance

Comment: if you paste your javascript here, someone might be able to fix it for your

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i got it to work!

this is what you need to change in the jquery dialog plugin
its a very good change because it makes the dialog work from an iframe as well as just a regular page

(this will only work if you are on the same domain )

this are the lines you need to change:

this one:

```
pTop = doc.scrollTop()
```

to this:

```
pTop = $(top.document).find("html").scrollTop()
```

and this one:

```
pTop += (wnd.height() - this.uiDialog.outerHeight()) / 2;
```

to this:

```
pTop += ($(top.document).find("html").attr("clientHeight") - this.uiDialog.outerHeight()) / 2;
```

that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

you should use self.parent to refer to the document object in which your iframe is contained when doing the calculations, else the calculations are based on the document object inside the iframe. This is what is currently causing your dialog to be in the center of the document object in the iframe and not the document object of the parent page containing the iframe. hope that make sense :)

Comment: yes ive said exactly that... i know what is causing the problem i just dont know what i need to do to the dialog to fix it.

which code to change and all that... also the fix have to be ok for a normal window too not just a window opened inside an iframe..
because there are other pages using this jquery plugin avcorse

tnx