# jQuery UI dialog in a cross-domain iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, iframe

I have an iframe with a long content. I have links that will pop-up jQuery UI dialog. The problem is that the dialog pops up in the center of the iframe, and not in the center of current viewport as in case without the iframe.

I have found several solutions:

- [JQuery UI Dialog inside of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15955595/684229)
- [positioning a jquery dialog that is inside an iframe realtive to the parent window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2773669/684229)
- http://www.alexdeveloper.com/blog/2012/4/17/iframe-and-jquery-ui-dialog-window-inside-how-to-show-it-centered

Unfortunatelly none of these work in cross-domain context - I always get `Permission denied` javascript error because the child iframe tries to access the parent window.

### Are there any solutions to this problem?

Can I for example parent allow a befriended `iframe` to access its properties? I tried it by setting the [`sandbox` attribute of `iframe`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp) to `<iframe ... sandbox="allow-same-origin">` , but it didn't help. The `iframe` is a trusted son of the parent page! There must be a way to say

```
OK my son, I trust you, you can access all of my properties!
```

Comment: You can have the iframe send a postmessage to the parent page, and have the parent page listen for said postmessage and open it's own dialog based on that message.

Comment: @KevinB well, that's complicated, the dialog sometimes contains also some scripts and active content which is bound to the iframed site.. I would be more interested in some solution when the parent says *"OK my son, I trust you, you can access all of my properties"*.

Comment: Right, but since you're dealing with the same-origin policy, your options are *very* limited.

Comment: @KevinB yes I know, but think: same origin policy to protect what or whom? Myself from myself? I, the creator of both parent and son pages, should be the one to set the rules.

Comment: If they use different origins, then no, they are not related and must abide by the same-origin policy.

Comment: I have a feeling I am speaking to wall...

Comment: The problem i'm seeing is that you keep trying to re-word the problem in different ways, but it doesn't change the fact that just because you own both the parent page and the iframe doesn't mean you can ignore the same-origin policy. If the sub domain, domain, port, or protocol is different in the iframe than it is in the parent page, the browser will restrict communication between the two to protect the user using the website from xss attacks.

Comment: without this protection, an advertisement included by an iframe would be able to bind an event to all forms on the parent page, allowing the advertisement to snif all data inputted into the parent website potentially stealing personal information.

Comment: @KevinB please go back and re-read the 4th comment from top... then you can delete your last two comments (or at least the last one).

Comment: the fact that you *created* the two pages has nothing to do with it. Here's a blog article outlining the very few ways of solving this problem: http://madskristensen.net/post/iframe-cross-domain-javascript-calls